# ElasticSearch using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

How can I implement Elastic Search Using Angular JS. For that I have created a sample page on angularjs in which it have 3 fields like Name,Address,Phone with submit button. Can any one suggest an approach to implementing elastic search using angular JS ? Thanks for all

Comment: What have you investigated/tried?

Comment: Read this http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2013/10/24/instant-search-with-angularjs-and-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

u can try read this http://www.elasticui.com
but just for angular 1